# A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    public static string GetChecksum(string m_fileinput)
    {


        string m_checksum;
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(m_fileinput))
        {
            SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
            m_checksum =
              BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
        }

        return m_checksum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("C://Users//wiproat3//Desktop//checksum.txt");
        string checksum = GetChecksum(fileContent);
        Console.WriteLine(checksum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I am trying to create checksum for a file .While debugging file contents are being red but i am getting this error "A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" in "filestream" line.

Comment: Read the exception message. You're passing a file's content to a method expecting a file name. Your actual question probably is _"How to create a stream from a string"_, which is documented thoroughly.

Comment: @CodeCaster there is a slim chance that the `checksum.txt` contains a single line that holds a path and filename ....

Comment: @rene yeah, theoretically, but then no ArgumentException would be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to correct your call to the `GetChecksum` function.

Right now you are passing the complete content of checksum.txt as a string to the m_fileinput parameter of `GetChecksum`. But `File.OpenRead` is expecting a file path - not the content of a file.

All you have to do, is updating your Main function, so it looks like the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string checksum = GetChecksum("C://Users//wiproat3//Desktop//checksum.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(checksum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```